# Clojure: How to start application even if database is not available?

Tags: database, clojure, config, component-diagram

I want to create a Clojure application that can use either a database or a configuration file to retrieve information.

I tried to disable the error message hoping that *db* would have the 'value' nil

```
(defstate ^:dynamic *db*
  :start (when-let [jdbc-url (env :database-url)]
           (conman/connect! {:jdbc-url jdbc-url})
           ; (do
             ; (log/warn "database connection URL was not found, please set :database-url in your config, e.g: dev-config.edn")
             ; *db*)
             )
  :stop (conman/disconnect! *db*))
```

I want to create only one application from which I can retrieve the name, version and ... of applications in a test environment. Not all these application have a database available in which we can add a table this information. Therefore I want to store this information in a configuration file. In this way I can deploy this little app as an API next to every application and use another application to call these API's and create a component-diagram in SVG.

Question: What should I do to be able to start this application if the database is not available?

Comment: Please add background on `defstate`

Comment: `defstate` is a function from `mount.core`.

Comment: Does removing the statement `(conman/connect! {:jdbc-url jdbc-url})` not help in the start process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above question I tried to solve my problem in the wrong file.
The way that worked for me was by disabling the first condition in -main in core.clj.

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (mount/start #'version-api2.config/env)
  (cond
    ; (nil? (:database-url env))
    ; (do
      ; (log/error "Database configuration not found, :database-url environment variable must be set before running")
      ; (System/exit 1))
    (some #{"init"} args)
    (do
      (migrations/init (select-keys env [:database-url :init-script]))
      (System/exit 0))
    (migrations/migration? args)
    (do
      (migrations/migrate args (select-keys env [:database-url]))
      (System/exit 0))
    :else
    (start-app args)))
```

To make my application fool proof I should change this validation to something like:
IF db not available THEN config file must be available.

However this solved my problem for now. :-)